# Fluid won't bake

Tags: fluid-simulation, baking

I have a simple scene set up, with a fluid object, a domain and an obstacle. When I press bake, nothing happens at all - there's no indicator that it's doing anything and nothing changes in the scene itself.

I've tried recalculating normals, increasing and decreasing the resolution and exporting the animated mesh, but nothing works.

[Here's the blend file.](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/36207)

Comment: Hi. Could you upload the .blend to [BlendExchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) instead of pasteall? .blends uploaded to pasteall get removed after a few months, making some questions that use it useless after the .blend gets removed. Blend Exchange doesn't remove the .blends so they can easily be accessed by people looking much later.

Answer (score 2):

For the life of my I don't know why, but to get it to bake you need to make your domain more like a cube. Scaling it along the z axis until it was about as tall as it is wide worked for me.

Comment: Thanks - I made everything a bit smaller and it did it for me. Do you know why the fluid doesn't interact with the obstacle?

Comment: @ayoungpythoner I hadn't noticed that, sorry. I really have no idea. The entire situation is really strange.

Comment: Due to the nature of how fluid (and smoke) sims are calculated the domains must be a cube.